# Leitura de dados sobre arquivo .csv

Tags: php, microsoft-excel, csv

Possuo um sistema em PHP realizando a leitura de dados de um arquivo csv. Ele apresenta o número do código de barras onde irei relacionar ao banco de dados para atualização de acordo com o arquivo enviado no sistema. Exemplo:

Usuário envia arquivo CSV com dados: 'Barras' => 7896603803918, 'qtd' => '1'

Ao fazer a leitura do arquivo recebo o valor de barras: "7,8966E+12" o qual não é o mesmo apresentado no valor correto.

Ao abrir o arquivo .csv no excel, encontro realmente o texto sendo exibido como "7,8966E+12", porem quando clico para verificar o valor da função, recebo o número correto de 7896603803918.

Meu problema se resume a: O arquivo .csv me envia um número exponencial que não representa o número real, impossibilitando a importação. Qual seria a solução correta para que eu pudesse retirar esses valores de forma correta do arquivo .csv ou se é um problema que todos enfrentam.

Código sendo utilizado no momento:

```
<?php
$csv = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('data.csv', 'r'), ';');
var_dump($csv);
```

Comment: O problema é que Excel ou qualquer outro programa que está utilizando para gerar a planilha está reconhecendo o código de barras como número e fazendo a formatação, gerando, assim, o csv de fóruns errada. Você precisa configurar no editor a coluna como texto

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente você está tentando passar barras para int, sendo que o maior valor para int32 é 2^32-32, tente passar o valor para string ou então tente usar uma versão 64 bits do php, que aceita int64